# For loop to print out columns that do not exist in both dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

I have two datasets one is called trained and the other is called tests, they are both a pandas data frame. The dataset trained has more columns than the dataset tests. I am still new to python I am trying to write a for loop that compares the columns of both dataframes and prints out the columns that are listed in trained but not tests.

Comment: That's a relatively simple task, and no doubt people here will be able to help you. However, we have no idea what you're working with, e.g., the name of your DataFrames, etc. The more details you give, the more people can help. Can you provide a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I realized where I made a mistake sorry about that. The name of the first dataframe is called trained and the name of the second dataframe is tests. the dataframe called trained has 313 columns while the test dataframe has 299 columns. When I try to run my lasso model I get an error due to the difference in columns. That is why I am trying to figure out which columns are in the dataframe trained that are not in the dataframe tests.

Comment: all columns in `tests` are present in `trained`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't ahve to do a `for` loop for this. You can just do

```
trained.columns[~trained.columns.isin(tests.columns)] #gives columns present in  trained but not is tests
```

Or

```
trained.columns[trained.columns.isin(tests.columns)] #gives columns present in both trained & tests df's
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but when I ran the code I got an error saying 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: you said you have pandas data-frames. Are you sure what you have are dataframe? if they are dataframe, they should have attribute `columns`.

Comment: If the answer helped you, consider up-voting & accepting the answer.